# Filter data in shell script

Tags: shell

In jcs.log file, I have this data:

```
Sep 24 20:30:02 2020 Mngmnt aplapl_a 43191001 HARMLESS 0 abc
Sep 25 20:30:23 2020 Mngmnt aplapl_a 43191002 HARMLESS 0 xyz
Sep 25 21:00:01 2020 Mngmnt aplapl_a 43191001 HARMLESS 0 123
Sep 25 21:00:01 2020 Mngmnt aplapl_a 43191001 HARMLESS 0 456
Sep 25 21:00:37 2020 Mngmnt aplapl_a 43191002 HARMLESS 0 funny
Sep 26 21:01:26 2020 Mngmnt aplapl_a 43191002 HARMLESS 0 test1
```

I have 2 variables:

```
startTime="2020-09-25 21:00:00"
endTime="2020-09-25 23:00:00"
```

I want to write a shell script, which will traverse each line and it should return me the line with the time is from $startTime to $endTime

How can I do this in shell script?

Comment: What have you tried?  I'd recommend making the date & time format in the variables match the ones in the log, btw ...

Comment: @tink Thanks for your replying. In shell script can it make the date & time format in the variables match the ones in the log?

Comment: It sure can ... it's just more effort.  But if the timestamp  in the log had a sensible iso format you could even get away w/ just using `awk` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a *hard wired* solution with your variables and the log file name in it.

```
#!/bin/bash
startTime="2020-09-25 21:00:00"
endTime="2020-09-25 23:00:00"
while read -r line
do
    current=$(date -d"$(echo $line|awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4}')" "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    if [[ $current = $startTime || $current > $startTime  ]] && [[  $current = $endTime || $current < $endTime ]]; then
        echo $line
    fi
done <jcs.log
```

When saved as `logie.sh`, `chmod +x logie.sh` it outputs the following:

```
./logie.sh 
Sep 25 21:00:01 2020 Mngmnt aplapl_a 43191001 HARMLESS 0 123
Sep 25 21:00:01 2020 Mngmnt aplapl_a 43191001 HARMLESS 0 456
Sep 25 21:00:37 2020 Mngmnt aplapl_a 43191002 HARMLESS 0 funny
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is very useful.

I want to search by keyword in result of above lines. When keyword is found, it return 0. Of course i can do this with looping each line. Can i improve this without looping? If i can't, can i loop from the last line in my file in shell script? 
How can i improve this code without looping each line?

Comment: @HãnhNguyễn -  I must say I don't understand what you're asking.  Can you please post a new question for this and be explicit as to what you're trying to achieve, including sample data and expected output?

Comment: **sample data**: the jcs.log file's data. 
**input**: startTime, endTime and **keyword**:  funny
**expected output**: 0 if no search result, 1 if funny is found. 
Traverse each line is good but it seems need more time when size of jcs.log file is larger.